# How do I iterate through multiple text(.txt) files in a folder on Google Drive to upload on Google Colab?

Tags: python, loops, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have a folder on Google Drive that consists of multiple text files. I want to upload them on Google colab by iterating through each file in the folder. It would be great if someone could help me out with this

Answer (score 1):

in order to read txt files from your google drive (not .zip or .rar folder):

First you have to mount (like most of colab codes which work along google drive at the same time)

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

then the following code will read any text file (any file ends with .txt) in path folder and save them to new_list.

```
import os

new_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/content/.../folder_of_txt_files"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as f:
                text = f.read()
                new_list.append(text)
```

obviously, you can save into a dictionary or dataframe or any data structure you prefer.

**note:** idk why but sometimes you need to change 'r' to 'rb'